# How to run Specflow tests one after another NOT parallel

Tags: c#, specflow, execution

I am running C# specflow tests from visual studio. When I run I am seeing tests are getting executed parallel. How can I make them to run one after another ? I am attaching snapshot which shows in cyan highlighted. I am looking a way to run them one after another. I am using Specflow.AssistDynamic and Techtalk.Specflow[image]

Comment: @mjwills - I think any specflow test with >= 2 tests would do. We do not require the posting of tons of starter template code.

Comment: I believe the answer is dependent on whether they are using `NUnit` or another option - https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Parallel-Execution . It seems to me that a [mcve] may be the fastest way for the OP to provide valuable context to get their problem answered. But I may be wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am able to do this by adding a property to AssemblyInfo.cs

[assembly: CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)]

Comment: Just a note - this can be added to any .cs file in the project. Especially important with the new auto-generated assembly info mechanism

Answer (score 0):

SpecFlow generates unit test code. so you need to check which xUnit framework you're using in that project.
See this link: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Parallel-Execution

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NUnit, then remove/comment this line from `Assembly.cs`:

```
[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
```

Also, as I remember, in a Visual Studio, in Test explorer, present button - Run tests parallely. Unclick it.
In my project, to do this, I removed this line, and also called test scenarios like: A_A, A_B, in alphabet. In this case they are going one after one.